# Using sqlalchemy and mysql-python， how to set charset=utf8mb4?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:123456@localhost:3306/tianchi?charset=utf8mb4')
```

Traceback:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2019, "Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: C:\mysql\\share\charsets\)")

[image]

sqlalchemy:1.2.7
Mysql-python:1.2.5
Mysql:5.7.13

Comment: What is the location of "utf8mb4" file?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-initialize-character-set.html

Comment: @KKK I don't know "utf8mb4” file name, and 'set names utf8mb4' works in MySQL client.

Comment: @Daniel E. I copyed "..\share\charsets\" to "C:\mysql\\share\charsets\",but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I replace 'mysqldb' with 'pymysql' and it works.Thank everyone.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! For me, the change was FROM: mysql+mysqlconnector TO mysql+pymysql